# Set Background on Root View (Relative Layout) using volley

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-volley

How would it be possible to set a image background to the root view (Relative layout) using volley from a remote server? Usually a drawable can be set to background using following :

```
  RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (R.id.rLayout);
  Resources res = getResources(); //resource handle
  Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newImage); 
  rLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

But i could not find a way to make drawable out of a image url except a method createFromPath(). I couldn't find how to use volley with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image from the URL like this:

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrlString);
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

And then apply it to your layout using your code like this:

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (R.id.rLayout);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), image)
rLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Please note, it's best to do this in an AsyncTask. The first two lines would go in doInBackground() and the last three lines would go in onPostExecute(). This is how I do it but I don't use Volley, I imagine that would be a lot more complex. If you want to use the Volley image caching then [this tutorial](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/volley-part-3-image-loader) is for you.

Comment: I guess that would have worked if i was using Async task. I just have to figure out how to do it using volley.

Comment: Check the link, it's all in there.